# VIM extreme slow startup analysis

Tags: vim

I did the profiling with the `--startuptime` option and got the following output. I could not immediately figure out where it went wrong:

```
000.000  000.000: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.000  000.000: Allocated generic buffers
000.000  000.000: locale set
000.000  000.000: clipboard setup
000.000  000.000: window checked
000.000  000.000: inits 1
062.000  062.000: parsing arguments
062.000  000.000: expanding arguments
062.000  000.000: shell init
062.000  000.000: Termcap init
062.000  000.000: inits 2
062.000  000.000: init highlight
1708007.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\syntax\syncolor.vim
1708022.000  031.000  031.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\syntax\synload.vim
1708069.000  047.000  047.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\filetype.vim
1708069.000  078.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\syntax\syntax.vim
1708085.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\filetype.vim
1708100.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\ftplugin.vim
1708116.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\indent.vim
1708116.000  140.000  062.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73/vimrc_example.vim
1708132.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\autoload\paste.vim
1708132.000  016.000  016.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73/mswin.vim
1708132.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\syntax\syncolor.vim
1708147.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\syntax\syncolor.vim
1708163.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\syntax\syncolor.vim
1708178.000  046.000  046.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\colors\desert.vim
1708178.000  202.000  000.000: sourcing $VIM\_vimrc
1708178.000  1707914.000: sourcing vimrc file(s)
1708194.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim
1708194.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\plugin\gzip.vim
1708194.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\plugin\matchparen.vim
1708210.000  016.000  016.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim
1708210.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\plugin\rrhelper.vim
1708210.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\plugin\spellfile.vim
1708210.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\plugin\tarPlugin.vim
1708210.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\plugin\tohtml.vim
1708210.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim
1708225.000  015.000  015.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\plugin\zipPlugin.vim
1708241.000  032.000: loading plugins
1708241.000  000.000: inits 3
1708241.000  000.000: setting raw mode
1708241.000  000.000: start termcap
1708241.000  000.000: clearing screen
1708241.000  000.000: opening buffers
1708241.000  000.000: BufEnter autocommands
1708241.000  000.000: editing files in windows
1708241.000  000.000: VimEnter autocommands
1708272.000  031.000: before starting main loop
1708272.000  000.000: first screen update
1708272.000  000.000: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

Can somebody help me find the high runners?

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue of my .vimrc sitting on a network drive. At my company, my %USERPROFILE% folder is mapped to a "user home" drive on the network. Vim takes this as the $HOME folder and stores the .vimrc there.

When not at the company, loading the file via the slower network connection slowed down the vim startup considerably.

The solution for me was to define a HOME environment variable and point it to a location local on my hard drive. That did the trick for me.

Comment: Jan, thanks for the reply, I'll check if this is also the case here.

Answer (score 0):

The "high runner" is pretty easy to find:

```
1708007.000  000.000  000.000: sourcing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\syntax\syncolor.vim
```

That it takes so much time is weird, though, as well as the `000.000` of the few first lines that is repeated all around the place.

IO errors? Bad auth? Bad installation?

Comment: it happens only when I use my laptop at home, I guess it's due to network change. Immediately when I get it back to company everything backs to normal.